# CakePHP / MongoDB: Read periodically fails

Tags: cakephp, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB on Ubuntu 11.10 with CakePHP 1.3 using the [cakephp-mongodb driver from ichikaway](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb), but I am seeing persistent connection problems.

My model is very simple. I am attempting a connect and a read

```
    $this->loadModel('Mongo.Mpoint');
    $data = $this->Mpoint->find('first');
```

However the result is inconsistent.  A significant amount of the time the server returns

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection
>   without sending any data.

However issuing a refresh, or several refreshes in quick succession will eventually deliver the expected returned data.  It feels like the server is going to sleep and needs to be woken up as repeatedly hitting return does not generate errors, but this is subjective.  The crash occurs in the find, not the connection itself.

I have rockmongo installed on the server which never fails to connect.  Also I see the same behaviour if I point the connection at a different sever (same version of mongo, but on centos) so I do not believe the issue is with mongodb itself.

I have attempted setting the connection to persistent and directly setting the timeout, all without success.

My colleague, who also has a copy of the app running directly on the centos server, says he saw this problem initially, but 'it went away'.

From what I can see therefore the issue is most likely in the cakePHP layer as connections across different servers yields the same result and a direct connection in PHP is trouble-free, but placing diagnostics does not reveal anything of immediate use.  It is rather odd to see a complete PHP crash with nothing useful returned from the server. Has anyone else seen this behaviour before and fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the Mongodb php driver. I had the same problem and I just upgraded from `1.2.7` to `1.2.9` and It seems to have been solved.

Just for reference
I am using

- Ubuntu 11.10 x86
- Xampp(Lampp) 1.7.7 with php-mongo-driver 1.2.9
- Mongodb 2.0.2
- CakePHP 2.0.6
- [cakephp-mongodb driver from ichikaway (Branch:cake2.0)](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/tree/cake2.0)